# How long to fully sync with blockchain via VPS?

Tags: blockchain, vps

How long should it take to fully sync the blockchain using a VPS?  My sync appears to be stuck at 334 days behind?

Answer (score 1):

It took mine around 5-7 hours - it does take time! If it appears stuck just type `exit` then start it up again, it will resume where it left off. If it continues to be stuck check:

- that port 18080 (default) is open (http://ismyportopen.com/) It should be if you already synced some data, but just rule that out.
- you have not exceeded your VPS storage allotment. I believe you should have at least 20 GB available, though more than that is recommended.